# Linking Textboxes to a dataset using a BindingSource

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, binding, sql-server-ce

This is the section of the form I am working on:

[image]

The following code links the BindingNavigator to the dataset using a bindingSource. Can I use this binding source to hook up the two text boxes to the data?

Do I simply need to use a property of the textboxes or is this more involved?

i.e when the form loads the first record's fields "Work Phrase" and "Description" will be displayed and when I scroll using the navigator the values in these boxes will change accordingly.

```
public partial class uxRevisionHelperForm : Form
{

    public SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WindFormAppRevisionHelper.Properties.Settings.DefinitionsDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    BindingSource definitionsBindingSource = new BindingSource();

    public uxRevisionHelperForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        uxDescriptionTextBox.AutoSize = true;
        this.hookUpBindingNavigator();
    }

    public void hookUpBindingNavigator()
    {            

        SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(new SqlCeCommand("Select * From tb_Definitions",conn));
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("Helper");
        ds.Tables.Add("DefinitionsTable");
        da.Fill(ds.Tables["DefinitionsTable"]);

        // Assign the BindingSource.
        this.uxBindingNavigator.BindingSource = this.definitionsBindingSource;
        this.definitionsBindingSource.DataSource = ds.Tables["DefinitionsTable"];

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the DataBinding collection of the textboxes.

Something like this:

```
uxDescriptionTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", 
                                      definitionsBindingSource,
                                      fieldInTable);
```

Comment: seems to work; I found this on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.BINDINGNAVIGATOR.BINDINGSOURCE);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true) which has a similar piece of code but with an extra argument in the `Add` method

Answer (score 1):

Have added the `full source code` (highlighting exactly your requirement) here - http://sdrv.ms/NyXHdu. Download > Open the solution in VS2010 > Hit F5

**[Update]**

1. Double click on Form.cs designer and observe the `productListBindingSource`. It bound to a custom object - `The ProductList class`
2. Then see the properties of the `TextBoxes` & `ComboBox` and observe the `DataBindings > Text property`. They are bound to the productListBindingSource's individual item. See Image below.

[image]

Courtsey - http://www.apress.com/9781590594391/ [Chapter 8]

Comment: +1 for the little app for me to nose around - I assume the answer to my question is in the file `form1.designer.cs` ...or is that all the boiler plate code?

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal , I tried the project link you can not access, If you don't mind can I ask for the link. [link](http://sdrv.ms/NyXHdu)